How would I get the correct sum of a dependent variable for a range of dates when there are inconsistent numbers of independent variables?
So this one's a doozy.
I'm pulling in a large table to Looker Studio from a BigQuery database regarding, let's say, total sales by cashier by day. There is other information relevant to each cashier for the day, which is what differentiates each row, but the last column shows the totals for some metric. The number of cashiers per day is not consistent, but will not have duplicates in the same day if that matters.
I want to create a scorecard for the total sales metric based on the date range. Unfortunately, this does not let me pick one specific item as it must be aggregated.
For example:



Date
Cashier
Irrelevant Info
Total Sales




1/1/24
X
foo
5


1/1/24
Z
bar
5


1/2/24
X
banana
10


1/2/24
Y
tom
10


1/2/24
Z
dick
10


1/3/24
X
larry
7


1/3/24
Y
whiskey
7


1/4/24
Y
tango
3


1/4/24
Z
foxtrot
3



I should expect the Total Sales aggregation in this example for the range of 1/1/24 - 1/4/24 to be 25.
The closest function I have come up with that is correct in some cases but not in others is:
((COUNT(Date)-COUNT_DISTINCT(Date))/(COUNT_DISTINCT(Date)*COUNT_DISTINCT(Cashier)))*SUM(Total Sales)

And this works in some cases, like the initial example and this one:



Date
Cashier
Irrelevant Info
Total Sales




1/1/24
X
foo
6


1/1/24
Y
bar
6


1/2/24
X
banana
3


1/2/24
Y
tom
3



My aggregation equation correctly evaluates this as 9 total sales.
But it breaks down in this example:



Date
Cashier
Irrelevant Info
Total Sales




1/1/24
X
foo
10


1/1/24
Y
bar
10


1/1/24
Z
banana
10


1/2/24
X
tom
5


1/2/24
Y
dick
5


1/2/24
Z
larry
5


1/3/24
X
whiskey
3


1/3/24
Y
tango
3


1/3/24
Z
foxtrot
3



My aggregation equation incorrectly evaluates this as 36 total sales.
Any info is appreciated. I know it's just a problem of mathematics and not the actual inner-workings of Looker Studio, but since I have to rely on the functions and limitations of it, I felt it fit best here.

Honestly you're trying to put a round peg in a square hole.  If it's in bigquery already, then put a view on top and then access the view in Looker Studio.  This is a simple group by in SQL.
The reason why your math isn't working is because you need a weighted average -- weighted by the context of how many of those values are in the same day with the context of the value itself. No?
